# How to plot strings to corresponding coordinates for printing?

Tags: c#, layout, printing, coordinates

My company gave me a project to automate the distribution of OR (Official Receipt).
My task is to create an application where the user will encode the OR information and the application will then print the OR (via printer). My problem is, the paper they'll print it on already has the layout. All I need to do is embed the encoded values from my application into that layout with the correct coordinates.

How can I achieve this using .NET Framework?

I already tried searching for Graphic.DrawString, but my major problem is plotting the correct coordinates for each value.

Thank You.

Comment: have done any actual attempt or test to print ONE value or character? code? then you can do the rest via trial and error, or actually measure and calculate it out. Or you expect we do the work so you can get paid? :-D

Comment: [PrinterUnitConvert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printerunitconvert)

Answer (score 0):

**Is the layout the users have the same for all users or can it change?**

i.e.
If "Receipt#" is at location 20,20 on one clients receipt will it be at the same location on the rest?

If the same location - use trial and error as Tomek suggests, if it is not then you will need to have a program to scan the receipt to an image and then parse the image for the words you are after.

**Are the data headings the same for all users or can that change too?**

i.e.
Do all clients have Receipt# on their receipts or can another client have ReceptNo instead?

If this is the case you not only need to parse for the easy headings but you now need to parse for the text and understand it via mappings.

Unless you are really good with image manipulation/parsing you will need to load the receipts into an OCR tool, or better yet convert into a PDF. The PDF will hold the names of the text as well as the locations of the text as meta data and can be parsed into your mapping file.